# Efficient algorithm for hierarchical traversing? JSON hydration, for example

Tags: graph, trees

I'm writing a small library that helps you hydrate JSON data into objects. Given this JSON example:

```
{
    "date": "1970-01-01 00:00:00",
    "foobar": "baz",
    "user": {
        "name": "foobar",
        "id": 2
    }
}
```

And the following library ruleset:

```
Hydrator hydrator = new Hydrator
hydrator.add("date", DateTime)
hydrator.add("foobar", String)
User user = hydrator.add("user", User)
user.add("name", String)
user.add("type", Integer)

DataSet data = hydrator.parse(jsonInput)
```

So far, it's working great. I have created a Node, and each Node can have children. I just walk through the entire JSON file, create Node instances for each key/value, and create the hierarchy. When i instance the node, i add some metadata. Then, in a big method, i walk through the entire node tree and hydrate depending on the metadata. However, i'm looking for an efficient way of doing this, since it ended up being a little slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fairly-standard [post-order depth-first traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order) should work nicely, in linear time on the number of nodes.  The main trick is traversing your hydrator tree and data tree together.  Post-order means all the dependencies will be instantiated before they're needed higher up.  In pseudocode, it would look something like this:

```
traverse(hydrator_node, json_node)
  for each child of hydrator node
    throw error if json_node doesn't have matching child
    recursively call traverse(hydrator_child, json_child)

  instantiate current node
```

Comment: That's faster than level-order? I mean, instantiating the current node and then going to the recursive function.

Comment: The advantage of post-order is your dependencies get instantiated first.  For example, you'll have `name` and `id` already hydrated when you go to make your `user`.  If you use in-order or pre-order, you end up doing weird workarounds to update those dependencies later, which usually costs you speed.